# Hibernate-Envers: Auditing dynamic-components

Tags: dynamic, components, hibernate-envers

As of the current version of Hibernate-Envers (4.3.0.Beta3) it is not possible to audit dynamic components.
An org.hibernate.MappingException is thrown: Audited dynamic-component properties are not supported. Consider applying @NotAudited annotation ...

However, in the Envers user manual, dynamic-components are not mentioned, event not under "Mapping Exceptions".

Is there a way to audit dynamic components with Hibernate-Envers?

Thinking about it, I don't see a reason why this could not be supported. Am I missing something?

Comment: As the exception says, these are not supported. See:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6003
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8049

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meanwhile, the audition of dynamic-components with Hibernate Envers has been implemented in hibernate-envers 4.3.0.RC1